# Is there a definitive model of the Elements as a Periodic Tetrahedral

Tags: periodic-table

i.e. Is there a specific reason why these diagrams exist? Is the "neatness" of the design simply a graphical representation of the mathematical constants, or is there some underlying reason why a person would envision this?

To be clear: I am asking if there is a physical phenomenon being portrayed or is this just a mathematical trick that is pleasing to the eye?

I have seen several depictions and they vary considerably in their complexity.
Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7o0kah6soA

[image]

Here is a site that is less of an incoherent jumble of science jargon.
(although it still says nothing about the underlying reason for applying it)
http://weise.symmetry-us.com/pythagorean-approach-in-chemistry-tetrahedron/
[image]

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/901/what-are-the-alternatives-to-the-periodic-table-of-the-elements?rq=1

Comment: I'm quite skeptical of how useful the linked diagram is. My skepticism greatly increased with the incoherent jumble of science jargon in the video.

Comment: "Normal" table is pretty much as good is it gets - it's based on actual periodicity. The ones you show aren't so it's rather "pleasing to the eye" thing then any serious stuff.